# ngRepeat not updating even though list is

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having a problem where despite a list being updated, ngRepeat does not display the information.

In the code below, the `$scope.selectedImages` array is being added to when images are selected using the file input. It is set up so that only unique files will be added to the list of selectedImages (no duplicates).

At the end of the function, `scope.selectedImages` prints the array with the new values, but in the view, ngRepeat does not add the new list items with the image names.

Other questions regarding this issue said that `$scope.$apply` should fix the problem, but for me it is not. Am I using it wrong or is there something else that I am misunderstanding.

EDIT: **View 1** and **View 2** are in separate HTML pages that both rely on the same controller.

**View 1:**

```
<input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" class="file-input" id="img-upload-btn" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().select(this)">
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised sidenav-btn" ng-click="proxy('img-upload-btn')">
  Select <strong>Images</strong>
</md-button>
```

The proxy function allows the `md-button` to click the input.

**View 2:**

```
<div layout-padding flex ng-controller="upload-controller">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="im in selectedImages">{{im.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.selectedImages = [];
$scope.select = function(element) {
  $scope.$apply(function(scope) {
    var justFiles = $.map(element.files, function(val, key) {
      return val;
    }, true);

    var fileEquality = function(f1, f2) {
      if (f1.name != f2.name) return false;
      if (f1.size != f2.size) return false;
      if (f1.type != f2.type) return false;
      if (f1.lastModified != f2.lastModified) return false;
      return true;
    }

    // inefficient, find better way later
    for (i in justFiles) {
      var contains = false;
      var file = justFiles[i];
      for (i in scope.selectedImages) {
        if (fileEquality(file, scope.selectedImages[i])) {
          contains = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!contains) scope.selectedImages.push(file);
    }
    console.log(scope.selectedImages);
  });
};
```

Comment: You didn't have a $scope.uploadedImages in your controller! this model is empty!

Comment: @HanArantes Oops! I had copied an older version of that code. Even with selectedImages, the problem arises and nothing is displayed. I edited in the newer code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input field template and controller template have to different scopes. Use `$rootScope.selectedImages` in your case.

Comment: is `file` input field placed inside your template of controller?

Comment: That might be the problem actually. I have two html files that depend on the controller, one is the sidebar for uploading which contains the input, and the other is the view that should display the files. Is there any way that I can keep these separate?

Comment: in your case your controller and input field have different scopes, that is why you don't see changes. Try to define selectedImages in `$rootScope`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks, if you edit your answer I'll edit my question to include the information about two separate html files that rely on the controller and accept your answer!